# PaperSize from default printer list

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I have a printer that a list of available paper sizes is from producer. How do I set the PapierSize from the list in the code?

[image: list of known paper sizes]

Comment: I am not a C# developer but while searching something similar for Java , I came across [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0280__Development/PrintersettingsDisplaythelistofvalidpapersizes.htm) .Does this help?

Comment: Nope, because driver of printer don't get info from system. I discovered that mitsubishi drivers for printer are sending some commands to printer and get the amount. I tried get info from manufacture but I never get response from my emails.